# How to pick up an object using a GUITexture

Tags: unity-game-engine, unityscript

How can I implement a `GUITexture` for picking up an object?

The problem is I have a GetButtonUp input, how can I change it to GUI Button?
The `use` is a layer type of my tag type. Here is the code:

```
#pragma strict

var Primary : Item;                     //Your Primary item holder


var Secondary : Item;                   //Your Secondary item holder

var myLayerMask : LayerMask;

private var HitItem : GameObject;       //Item that raycast hits.


function Update ()
{

if(Input.GetButtonUp("Use"))            //Remember to make new Input called "Use" :)
{
var hit: RaycastHit;
var Direction = transform.TransformDirection(Vector3.forward);
Debug.DrawRay(transform.position, Direction * 2.5, Color.blue);         //Shows raycast      when you press "Use"

    if(Physics.Raycast(transform.position, Direction, hit, 2.5, myLayerMask))
    {
                    if(hit.transform.tag == "Item")         //If raycast hits   transform.tag "Item".
                    {
                            HitItem = hit.transform.gameObject;     //HitItem becomes  hit.gameObject.
                            var ItemScr : ItemScript =  HitItem.GetComponent("ItemScript");

                            if(ItemScr.MyItem.IsSecondary)  //If Hit item is Secondary
                            {
                                    if(Secondary.ActiveObj == null) //Checks if you dont  have Secondary Item
                                    {
                                            Secondary = ItemScr.MyItem;
                                            Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
                                            if(Primary.ActiveObj == null)   //Checks if  you have already
                                            {                               //equipped  item in your hand.
                                                    Secondary.ActiveObj.active = true;
                                            }
                                            else if(Primary.ActiveObj)
                                            {
                                                    if(Primary.ActiveObj.active ==  false)
                                                    {
                                                            Secondary.ActiveObj.active = true;
                                                    }
                                            }

                                    }
                            }
                                                                    //And same to primary :)
                            if(!ItemScr.MyItem.IsSecondary) //If Hit item is Primary
                            {
                                    if(Primary.ActiveObj == null)   //If you don't have primary, goes on...
                                    {
                                            Primary = ItemScr.MyItem;
                                            Destroy(hit.transform.gameObject);
                                            if(Secondary.ActiveObj == null)
                                            {
                                                    Primary.ActiveObj.active = true;
                                            }
                                            else if(Secondary.ActiveObj)
                                            {
                                                    if(Secondary.ActiveObj.active ==  false)
                                                    {
                                                            Primary.ActiveObj.active = true;
                                                    }
                                            }
                                    }

                            }
                    }
    }


}

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Any call with GUI needs to be called in the OnGUI() method. And usually GUI scripts are put separate from other parts of your program and attached to the main camera or an empty object.
-Personally I use main camera.
Unity had a good walk through [Here](https://docs.unity3d.com/Documentation/Components/GUIScriptingGuide.html)

And if you want to change to c# i suggest google, which I believe should be a perfect source for this type of question.